# Not able to left align node at line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to have a node above and left aligned with my line. Here is the code:

```
\draw (0.5,0.5) node[anchor=west, above, sloped] {Tisch} -- (3.5,0.5);
```

I am using the Tikz package...
But the node only align in the mittle above the line. Do you guys have an idea? I am quite new to latex :)

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. What is you complete minimal working example?

Comment: Please edit your question starting from \documentclass until \end{document}. Delete the comment.

Comment: the whole document? ist about 200 lines...

Comment: Does `\draw (0.5,0.5)  -- (3.5,0.5) node[anchor=south west, pos=0, sloped] {Tisch};` help? What @Sebastiano means is that you should prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to help us help you...

Comment: @Rmano Grazie very much for your support.

Comment: Ah, here is the MWE: `\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Tisch
    \draw (0,0) -- (4,0);
    \draw (0.5,0) -- (0.5,0.5);
    \draw (0.5,0.5) node[anchor=west, above, sloped] {Tisch} -- (3.5,0.5);
    \draw (3.5,0.5) -- (3.5,0);
    

    \draw (0,3) -- (4,3);
    
    
    \draw[->, thick] (2,1.5) -- (2,2.5) node[midway, right] {Decke};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`
And south west does not work (anchor).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not entirely clear, what you after, so I guess that it may be the following:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0.5,0.5) node[above right, inner xsep=0pt] {Tisch} -- (3.5,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, right guess. Thanks a lot...
Have great day

Comment: @Jufeus, you are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You can also manually apply a horizontal shift to the current position:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0.5,0.5) node[above left, xshift=2.5em]{Tisch} -- (3.5,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Analogously, there is the `yshift` option to adapt the vertical position. But the solution of @Zarko is more idiomatic and hence, recommended.